# Android app using Google Maps library, installable everywhere

Tags: android, google-maps

Is it possible to use Google Maps Android library in my app in a way, that the app can be installed even on phones without Google Maps? On phones without Google Maps, the maps feature would be disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use Google Maps Android library in my app in a way, that the app can be installed even on
>   phones without Google Maps?

There is an undocumented `android:required="false"` flag you can put on the `<uses-library>` element. I am hopeful that they will document this in a future release. With that set to `false`, you would need to use reflection to see if Google Maps is loaded (e.g., try to find the `MapView` class) -- if not, disable whatever would lead the user to a map.

Comment: When Maps library isn't present, you can use a WebView wrapper around the Map Web interface.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody else has the same problem (I do):

On [this Android Developer page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html#maps) it says -- as far as I can tell -- that you can reference the Maps API and thus have e.g. a map activity in your app by using **Google Play services**:

> "The Google Maps Android APIs are not included in the Android
> platform, but are available on any device with the Google Play Store
> running Android 2.2 or higher, through [Google Play
> services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html).
>
> To integrate Google Maps into your app, you need to install the Google
> Play services libraries for your Android SDK. For more details, read
> about [Google Play
> services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html)."

Apparently it is an actual app (it is installed on my phone) that updates certain Google stuff.

So it seems it is possible, but *only for devices running Android 2.2 (API level 8) and above*.
I find the explanation on that site a bit unclear, however, and I have not been able to test this on my own.

In my case, I guess I have to live with the fact that not all devices will be able to install my app, since I target an API < 8.